# Why copying a Scala array using keyword yield gives me a vector

Tags: scala, types

I tried to copy a Scala array using the *yield* keyword, but I got an vector in the end. Why and how can I get an copied array using yield?

```
    scala> val s=Array(1,2,3,4,5); val copied_s=for (i<-0 until s.size) yield s(i)
```

The console returns

```
s: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
copied_s: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: `.clone` is definitely a way to go in your case, but if you want `for` loop: `for(e <- s) yield(e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use clone instead:

```
val c = s.clone
```

0 until ... creates a Range, and this is the source, from which the Vector is considered a good fit, not the Array.

```
scala> 0 until 4
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

A big (...) helps too:

```
(for (i<-0 until s.size) yield s(i)).toArray
```

but clone is much smaller.